# Devise sometimes signs out users on edit_user_registrations_path in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

So I'm breaking my head trying to figure this out: When users navigate to the `edit_user_registration_path` they sometimes are signed out. This only happens in production (we're running on heroku with 2 dyno's currently, I've tried scaling back to one but that didn't help). We're using subdomains for multi tenancy and using SSL on production. In development this has never happened and specs checking this are also passing.

We're on `Rails 4.1.4`, `Devise 3.2.4` and `Warden 1.2.3`

Our app is open source, the repo is over at https://github.com/DefactoSoftware/Hours but some small snippets of things we've customized:

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

app/controllers/users/registrations.html.erb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  protected

  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    user = super(hash)
    user.organization = current_account
  end
end
```

app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <h2> <%= t('registration.edit', resource_name: resource.class.model_name.human) %>    </h2>
    <%= gravatar_image_tag(resource.email, gravatar: { secure: true }, class: "image-circle", title: resource.full_name) %>
    <p><%= t("registration.gravatar_instructions_html") %></p>
    <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <div class="form-inputs edit-user">
        <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>

        <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
          <p><%= t('registration.pending_information', unconfirmed_email:     resource.unconfirmed_email) %></p>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", hint: t('registration.hint.blank'),required: false %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: false %>
        <%= f.input :current_password, hint: t('registration.hint.current_password'), required: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, t('registration.update_button') %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to t('back'), :back %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried searching for people with similar issues but I couldn't find anyone having issues with just opening `edit_user_registration_path`.

The issue on our repo is here:
https://github.com/DefactoSoftware/Hours/issues/139

Hope anyone can point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: what does the logs says, it shows sometimes redirection halted.. check out that .it may help

Comment: It doesn't even seem to get to the endpoint when it fails so it might be something in warden?